# call functions on events NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

actually i'm trying to call the function demandConnexion after an event, but it is working for me , it telles me that "this.demandeConnexion is not a function" . how can i get it to work ? help , this is the code  :

```
Serveur.prototype.demandConnexion = function(idZEP) {

     if (this.ZP.createZE(idZEP))

         {

         console.log(' ==> socket : demande de creation ZE pour '+idZEP +' accepte');

         }

     else

         {

         console.log(' ==> socket : demande de creation ZE pour '+idZEP +' refuse');

         }
};

Serveur.prototype.traitementSurConnection = function(socket) {

    // console.log('connexion');

    console.log(' ==> socket connexion');

    // traitement de l'evenement DEMANDE DE CONNEXION D'UNE ZE

    socket.on('connection', (function(idZEP) { this.demandConnexion(idZEP)

        console.log('good')

}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when the callback is called "this" isn't your "Serveur" instance. In your case try something like

```js
var that = this;
socket.on('connection', (function(idZEP) { 
    that.demandConnexion(idZEP)
    console.log('good')
}))
```

or

```js
socket.on('connection', this.demandConnexion.bind(this));
```

An other solution (the best in my opinion) would be to use the arrow functions to keep the same scope as the closure

```js
socket.on('connection', ()=>{
  //here this refers to your Serveur (the enclosing scope)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the function it is called in. As you are using node.js, you could either use an arrow function to make `this` available in the context you think it's in now, or set `this` to a variable outside of the function.

```
socket.on('connection', idZEP => this.demandConnexion(idZEP))
```

Or

```
var that = this;
socket.on('connection', function(idZEP) { that.demandConnexion(idZEP) });
```